# Updating aws-sdk v2 to v3 breaks DynamoDB call in Synthetics Canary

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk, aws-sdk-js, aws-sdk-js-v3

Interesting issue after updating to v3. The updated code works fine in tests, locally and in lambdas, but fails when running it within a Synthetics Canary. Might be an easy solution, but haven't found it yet :/ Using the new v3 style with send() and GetItemCommand makes no difference.

Edit: With fails, is that the getItem()-call doesn't return the DynamoDB item. As seen from the logs, metadata is returned, but the actual Item is missing.

The only obvious thing I've noticed is that v2 makes https calls, while v3 makes http calls. I tried changing the `endpoint` and `tls` within the client options, but doesn't seem to make a difference either.

Old v2

```
'use strict';

const DynamoDBClient = require('aws-sdk/clients/dynamodb');

const dynamodb = new DynamoDBClient({ apiVersion: '2012-08-10' });

async function getAttributeByKey(table, keyName, keyValue, attributeName) {
  const params = {
    TableName: table,
    Key: {
      [keyName]: { S: keyValue },
    },
  };
  const {
    Item: { [attributeName]: { S: attributeValue } = {} } = {},
  } = await dynamodb.getItem(params).promise();
  return attributeValue;
}

Canary logs:
2024-02-26T07:45:30.926Z INFO: {"TableName":"<table>","Key":{"<key>":{"S":"<value>"}}}
2024-02-26T07:45:30.928Z INFO: Request: https://dynamodb.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/ 
2024-02-26T07:45:30.954Z INFO: Response: 200 OK Request: https://dynamodb.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/ 
2024-02-26T07:45:30.955Z INFO: {"Item":{"<key>":{"S":"<value>"},"modified":{"S":"2024-02-21T16:39:48.336Z"},"<attribute>":{"S":"<value>"}}}
```

New v3:

```
'use strict';

const { DynamoDB } = require('@aws-sdk/client-dynamodb');

const dynamodb = new DynamoDB({ apiVersion: '2012-08-10' });

async function getAttributeByKey(table, keyName, keyValue, attributeName) {
  const params = {
    TableName: table,
    Key: {
      [keyName]: { S: keyValue },
    },
  };
  const {
    Item: { [attributeName]: { S: attributeValue } = {} } = {},
  } = await dynamodb.getItem(params);
  return attributeValue;
}

Canary logs:
2024-02-26T07:52:39.813Z INFO: {"TableName":"<table>","Key":{"<key>":{"S":"<value>"}}}
2024-02-26T07:52:39.815Z INFO: Request: http://dynamodb.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/ 
2024-02-26T07:52:39.825Z INFO: Response: 200 OK Request: http://dynamodb.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/ 
2024-02-26T07:52:39.826Z INFO: {"$metadata":{"httpStatusCode":200,"requestId":"<...>","attempts":1,"totalRetryDelay":0}}
```

Comment: Define "breaks"…? It would be much better to share what failed than share what succeeds, as all I see is successful code.

Comment: @LeeroyHannigan edited to explain that the call is successful, but missing the Item information.

Comment: I get the exact same thing for API Gateway V2, it appears that the casing of responses it lowercase, at least in the Synthetics list

Comment: @WilliamBradley any solution for your issue?

Comment: @lobbin use AWS SDK V2 

Answer (score 0):

I have no issue with the code. I would remove the mapping you have on the Item attribute, and just try to print the entire response.

Also ensure that an item exists with the specific key you are passing in.

#### My item

[image]

#### My code

```
const { DynamoDB } = require('@aws-sdk/client-dynamodb');

const dynamodb = new DynamoDB({});

async function getAttributeByKey(table, keyName, keyValue, attributeName) {
    const params = {
        TableName: table,
        Key: {
            [keyName]: { S: keyValue },
        },
    };
    const {
        Item: { [attributeName]: { S: attributeValue } = {} } = {},
    } = await dynamodb.getItem(params);
    return attributeValue;
}

const run = async () => {
    const x = await getAttributeByKey("test1", "PK", "123", "other")
    console.log(x);
}

run();
```

#### My Result

```
$ node test.js
lee
```

Comment: Yes, inherited that ugly bit :)

The code works fine locally and in lambdas, it’s only in the Canary it breaks. 

The last log line is the full response from getItem.

Comment: It seems to me your just reaching the wrong table or an item that does not exist. What's different about the Canary code?

Comment: I can replace the v3 version with the previous v2 version and everything works as expected again. That’s why I don’t understand this at all.

Comment: But you don't change the logic to V3… your still using GetItem and not client.send()?

Comment: Correct, not changing any logic. More or less change the package in require() and remove the call to promise().

Comment: V3 uses client.send() for API calls, so you'll have to overhaul the API itself also.

Comment: I've tried client.send(), but gives the same result as the above. Still works fine in tests and lambdas though.